# Xcode target Deployment Target vs. project Deployment Target

Tags: iphone, xcode

Excuse my ignorance, but what is the difference in Xcode between the Deployment Target field under "Targets" and the deployment target under "Project"?

What happens if my project deployment target is 3.2, and my iOS Application Target is 4.0? Or vice versa?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Target settings override project settings. Project settings are valid for all targets whose settings haven't been overridden.

Comment: Should they be set to the same value then? or iOS Application Target >= project deployment target, because if it is overwritten by higher from target it wont work on lower iOS?

Comment: If you have just one target in your project (or if all targets should share the same Deployment Target), just set it once for your projects and the targets will inherit the setting. If you have multiple targets with different deployment target settings, you must set it explicitly on all targets that deviate from the project-level setting.

Comment: @OleBegemann, Your answer has been plagiarised [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11340551/916299)

Comment: @JamesWebster: Thanks, but it's just two sentences, let's not make a big deal out of it.

Comment: I see it's the accepted answer, but it seems wrong. I'm adding an answer that should better reflect the differences, including link to apple docs for reference.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE:**
As clarified by mr. @Edward, **the version at "project" level** serves as **default**, whereas **the version at "target" level** **overrides** the default value.

Actually it's written in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html):

> "Target settings override project settings."

The Base SDK is not related to any of this.

**Original post:**

Looking at the [link form Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html) ... Looks like when you set **the version at "target" level** you specify the minimum required version that a user can have to run your app.

On the other side, by setting **the version at "project" level** you specify what SDKs are available to you when you're developing. So if an API is available only to the latest version you get a compiler error notifying you that you have to handle the behaviour for missing API differently (probably using `#available` or `@available` ).

[image]

This is how I understand the above image:

- you can use all APIs from major version,
- your users can download the app only if they have at least "Deployment target" version installed
- you can use APIs up until the "Base SDK" version
- APIs above "Base SDK" version are not available to you in your project

Comment: The iOS Deployment Target on the project page is not the Base SDK. Whether you change the iOS Deployment Target via the Xcode UI for the project or a target, in the project file the variable that gets changed is always `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`.

Comment: Hmm, I'd say it's just an unfortunate coincidence that the affected variable has the **same name for both changes** in `project.pbxproj` file (as @EdwardBrey noticed the name is `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`). However that still does not clarify completely why the **two different settings**, but indeed the `deployment_target` has two different meanings on a project UI vs. on a target UI.

Comment: There are 4 occurrences of `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET ` in `project.pbxproj `, if you have a project with just 1 target.  I guess it's 2 times for project setting (debug and release) and 2 times for target setting (again, debug and release).

Comment: As you noted, by default a target has two instances of `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET `: one for debug and one for release. The project has a corresponding pair. All 4 properties pertain to the Deployment Target. None pertain to the Base SDK. The properties' names aptly describe their function. The reason for two pairs is that the project's serve as defaults whereas the target's serve as [optional overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64443872/145173).

Answer (score 8):

The iOS Deployment Target on the Project page is the default for all targets in the project. The iOS Deployment Target on each project is an optional project-level override.

To set a target to inherit from the project, you can't use the "General → Deployment Info" section. Instead, go to "Build Settings → Deployment", and for "iOS Deployment Target" choose "Other..." and enter `$(inherited)`.